# Writing basis involving Euler's formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $V =  [a \cos t + b \sin t : a, b \in \mathbb{C}]$ and consider

$D = \frac{d}{dt}: V \to V$

Firstly, compute the matrix representation of D with respect to the basis $[\cos t, \sin t]$. Secondly, compute the matrix representaton of D with respect to the basis $[e^{it},e^{-it} ]$.

So far, I have thought of this for the first part:

$\frac{d}{dt}([a \cos t + b \sin t ) = (-a \sin t + b \cos t)$

So would the matrix representation for this part be $\begin{bmatrix}
    b  \\
    -a 
\end{bmatrix}$?

I suppose for the second half of the question I am supposed to use Euler's Formula to figure out the matrix representation. I know that

$e^{it} = \cos t + i\sin t$ and $e^{-it} = \cos t - i\sin t$. Should I also consider how $\frac{e^{it}+ e^{-it}}{2} = \cos t$ and how $\frac{e^{it}- e^{-it}}{2i} = \sin t$? How would I write the matrix representation of the second part?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, especially about the notation, nevertheless:

for the first basis $[\cos t,sin t]$ represent the vector and matrix as
\begin{equation} V =
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}, 
D = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
D(V) = \begin{bmatrix}
b\\
-a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
such that the derivative is satisfied. 
For the second basis $[e^{it},e^{-it}]$ represent the vector and matrix as
\begin{equation}
 V =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b i\\
\frac{1}{2}a - \frac{1}{2}b i
\end{bmatrix},
D = \begin{bmatrix}
-i & 0\\
0 & i
\end{bmatrix},
D(V) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}b - \frac{1}{2}ai\\
\frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}ai
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
such that again the derivative is satisfied.